# Django template response middleware

Tags: django, middleware

I'm writing some middleware for my Django application, and am stuck when trying to write the process_template_response function. I'm familiar with templates and rendering, but am puzzled as to how to pass dictionary values to the template based on some if/else statements I wrote in the process_request function. My middleware's purpose is to issue redirects based on auth status, and I need to pass a message saying 'Not authorised' when someone requests a page they are not supposed to see.

Here's the middleware:

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

class CustomMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response = None):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.permittedPages = settings.PERMITTED_PAGES
        self.noLoginRequired = setting.NO_LOGIN_PAGES

    def process_request(self, request):
        request_path = request.path.lstrip('/')
        if request_path not in noLoginRequired  and request_path in permittedPages and request.user.is_authenticated == False:  HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

        elif request_path not in permittedPages and request.user.is_authenticated: #if the page isn't accessible but the user is logged in
            not_found_message = 'This page isn\'t available, redirecting to the home page....'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/'), not_found_message
        else: #if the page isn't accessible and the user isn't logged in
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

    def process_template_response(self, request):
```